# Basically a 'does not contain a definition' and ' no accessible extension method' type problem

Tags: compiler-errors, arguments, contains, definition, assembly-references

I use Unity. Node is a script that is making public bools and variable that is referenced by all scripts so its not that important and the script with the error is called Enemymover, with coordinates being a public Vector2Int in Node. Im basically getting an error of:

Assets\Enemy\EnemyMover.cs(54,82): error CS1061: 'Node' does not contain a definition for 'coodinates' and no accessible extension method 'coodinates' accepting a first argument of type 'Node' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried resetting all my scripts as implied by another Q&A but it doesnt work, my script is down below for reference:
 IEnumerator FollowPath()
{
for(int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
{
Vector3 startposition = transform.position;
Vector3 endposition = gridManager.GetPositionFromCoordinates(path[i].coodinates);
float travelspeed = 0f;

```
            transform.LookAt(endposition);

            while(travelspeed < 1f)
            {
                travelspeed += Time.deltaTime * speed;
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startposition, endposition, travelspeed);
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
        }
    
        FinishPath();`}
```

``

If someone can help me that would be great :).

The script was suppose to move a prefab varient called enemy Ram, though none of the errors are from the prefab or its creation. I was expecting the coordinates of the detination of that prefab to be recorded for a pathfinder script although that isnt what happened and I instead got the error seen above